# Compare two strings which differ only slightly

Tags: string, bash

I have the following function to count the number of differences between two Strings:

```
get_num_diffs_strict() {
    local -i diffs=$(cmp -l <(echo "$1") <(echo "$2") 2>/dev/null | wc -l)

    local -i lendiff=0
    if (( ${#1} > ${#2} ));then
        lendiff=$((${#1} - ${#2}))
    else
        lendiff=$((${#2} - ${#1}))
    fi

    if (( lendiff > 0 ));then # lines differ in length
        (( lendiff-- )) # subtract already accounted EOF character
        (( diffs+=lendiff ))
    fi

    echo $diffs
}
```

For inputs like

```
$ get_num_diffs_strict hello somethingelse
$ 13
$ get_num_diffs_strict hello holla
$ 2
```

the results are acceptable.
For other input strings I would like it to be less strict with what is deemed as a difference. Consider the following cases

```
$ get_num_diffs_strict hello helo
$ 2
$ get_num_diffs_strict hello heello
$ 3
$ get_num_diffs_strict 0123456789 0123567889
$ 4
```

The desired output, however, should be 1 in the first two cases and 2 in the last one.
In case 1 and 2 there is only one letter missing or just one additional letter. It should count as one difference. In the last case the second string is missing the number 4 and contains the number 8 twice. These should count only as two differences - like a human would intuitively perceive it.

Is there any program, similar to `cmp`, that can accomplish that? Alternative solutions (python, perl, etc.) are also acceptable. I am merely trying to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This is called "edit distance" and there are many, many algorithms, libraries and programs that can calculate it: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance Damerau-Levenshtein is probably the most common, would yield the result you want, and is easy to implement in any language if you don't want to use an existing implementation.

Comment: Search for the term “Levenshtein distance”, it is probably already implemented in all major programming languages.

Comment: @Jordan Thanks, that is a good starting point.

Comment: P.S. I misspoke; Damerau-Levenshtein is not an algorithm but rather a particular edit distance metric. See the above linked article for algorithms.

Comment: you can use python, package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/editdistance, comparisons will be one-liners.